# Hiding documents for an index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case where in  I need to soft delete documents from an index in elastic-search.

Sample Scenario :

```
Elastic-search (ES)  -> index1 

[ doc1 , doc2, doc3, ... docn]
```

Now an ES query fetches me documents which match the query. Say the resultant documents are

```
[doc4, doc5,doc6]
```

Now I need to soft delete document doc5 so that it still exists in ES, but my resultant set
is instead

```
[ doc4, doc6]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this scenario on ES?

One possible solution I thought was to move my document (example : doc5) to a newer index under the same ES instance.

But I'm keen to know if there are other ways to get around.

Comment: another approach you could probably add a not_searchable field and set it to true for the document you want to soft delete and in the search query filter on documents which have this field missing but since update is no better than a delete & insert i do not think this approach is any better than the one you have

Comment: @keety : Thanks a lot for the reply. I've thought about this way which is perfectly valid but the thing is we expose elastic search cluster within our organization and even with an added field like you suggested,  if a person's query  wraps  the 'non-searchable' field , it's going to still expose the document and the new 'non-searchable' field. I should've given better context of the problem at hand.